# Deleted an error log and it won't regenerate

Tags: nginx, vps, centos6

I'm a novice and hoping that someone with more experience can help me with this. I am running a VPS with CentOS 6.7 and nginx. The error log was getting very large and I was worried it would take up more space, so I deleted it thinking that it would regenerate by itself. While the website is still online, now the error log is not being created at all. I created a file in the same location as the old error log, as well as tried restarting nginx, but it still isn't being populated. One may think this is because I solved the error, which I did, but the access log is not being populated either, even when I visit the site, and the error log is still empty even when I purposely cause an error myself.

The error log was located at /home/admin/web/domainname.tld/logs/domainname.tld.error.log and now it is just empty.

Comment: 1) Did you restart nginx? 2) Are the ownership and permissions on the file correct?

Comment: I restarted nginx, and it restarted successfully but still no error log. The file is owned by root, I thought this was what the file was supposed to be owned by.

Comment: It needs to be owned by whatever user nginx is running as.

Comment: I guess you didn't restart nginx. Try to stop it, confirm that it's stopped and then start again. Also check that your config contains `error_log` directive with proper path to log file.

Comment: nginx is running as multiple users, how do I know which one is looking for the error log? In reply to Alexey, that's not the correct error log. Looking in nginx's folder I can see an error.log file, and that one has no issue. The one that has an issue is the error log for this one domain, located at /home/admin/web/domainname.tld/logs/domainname.tld.error.log (PS sorry for the long delay)

Comment: I just tried with all three users nginx was running as and permissions changed to 777, restarting nginx each time a permission was changed. The log is still empty.